# MySQL update datetime column data only when it has changed for that record

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

We get data from a JSON feed that gives us several objects, some of that data is committed to a local database. New objects sometimes do not have a 'time' field yet, but they will later. When an object does not have the 'time' field the local DB time is used.

When the object that was missing the 'time' field eventually get it we want to update the record in the database. We only want to update the record if the 'time' field is different, so the 'time' of the JSON field and the 'time' in the database need to be compared and the record updated when it is different.

The JSON object has a 'transaction' field which we add to the database, it is unique and can be used to match the record.

TL;DR Long and the short of it, match on 'transaction' and update 'time' if it is different.

This is a sample of the database. 
[enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/538cc/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why simple update is not enough?

`UPDATE wp_user_txt SET`time`=:time,`message`=:message ... WHERE`transaction`=:transaction AND (`time`IS NULL OR`time`<> :time )`

?